# Http Request from Azure SQL Stored Procedure (no CLR)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I'm moving an on-premise SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database.
From inside a stored procedure, we need to make HTTP request.
I had built a CLR assembly to make HTTP request, and all was working well.

From what I understand, CLR Assemblies are not supported by Azure SQL Database.
So I have to find an alternative,

Note that the use of stored procedure is for a legacy app to communicate with our app.
The legacy app cannot make an HTTP request (or the devs don't know how).
So basically it goes like:

Legacy App --> Our Stored Proc --> Our Web App.

I'm looking for the simplest solution for an Azure SQL Database stored procedure to make a call to a Web App.

I would prefer no polling solution, ie: Legacy App insert row, then our Web App pools the database.

Comment: This is an abuse of SQLCLR. It's *not* meant to be used to query other systems and cause delays to the database itself while waiting for slow responses. In fact, you had to crack open security to allow external calls, which should be a warning that this is wrong. Just don't do this.

Comment: If anything, think that you are asking for a way to break through a data center's firewalls, call unknown sites from the provider's servers with unknown or missing encryption.

Comment: An alternative would be to create an Azure Function that would be [triggered by some event](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-storage/) (eg entries in an Azure queue), execute the HTTP call and process the results

Comment: To be clear, I do not query other systems and wait for response, I send a command and don't wait for return.

Comment: Azure Function was an idea, I was looking at the HTTP trigger, but same problem

Comment: Any example how to insert into an Azure Queue from a Stored Proc ?

Comment: Same which problem? If you want the *database* to make an HTTP call, you can easily make an HTTP call from the application. Or you can use the SDK to make this easier. Just send messages to a queue for each new row you want processed, or after inserting a batch of rows

Comment: You can't make anything from inside a stored procedure and shouldn't even be thinking about it. There is no excuse why the application, or a utility can't make requests or post messages to a queue. It can't be security for sure, as you ask for a way to bypass the security of a far, far ,far more sensitive resource like a database

Comment: The legacy app development is out of my control, they only know how to call a stored procedure :-(

Comment: Another option would be to enable [change tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322(v=sql.110).aspx) on the tables you care about and use a time trigger to poll for changes since the last poll. Change Tracking has minimal impact since it stores the PK values of the rows that changed and the operation type. It only returns changes after a specific version number, so you don't have to worry about processing unchanged data. It's typically used to synchronize databases and load data warehouses with changes precisely because it has such a low impact